# Intuitive explanation for summing the embedding and positional encoding in the Transformer's embedding

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, word-embeddings, transformers

In the Transformer model, the embedding and positional encoding are summed together to represent a word in each location ('positional embedding' from now on).

This way, each cell contains semantic and positional information. However, since two types of information are represented by one number only, it seems unclear to which extent semantic information and positional information are represented in each cell.

For example:

`word1 = [0.2, 0.1, -0.3]`

Can be the sum of:

```
embedding1 = [-0.34,0.52,0.69]
positional_encoding1 = [0.54,-0.42,-0.99]
```

Or from:

```
embedding1 = [-0.64,-0.81,0.16]
positional_encoding1 = [0.84,0.91,0.14]
```

Hence, summing two cells makes no sense to me. Yet, Transformers are very effective algorithms, so I probably miss something. Is the problem that I describe a problem indeed? And can someone provide an intuitive explanation for summing the embedding and positional encoding?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this?  I'm learning about transformers and immediately had this question as well.  I wonder if maybe there's sufficient dimensionality in the embedding that the position encoding only has the effect of creating new variations of the original words rather than distorting the "meanings" of the words (i.e., shifting the embeddings in such a way to blur them with words with different meanings).  Maybe any blurring effects are small relative to the effects of the increased dimensionality that would be required to account for position separately.

Answer (score 3):

Positional encoding is typically a deterministic function, so it's always the same on all inputs. You are adding the same vector to all of your inputs.

For example, if you were using a naive positional encoding, you would use

`positional_encoding = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]` for all inputs.

In [Attention Is All You Need](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/file/3f5ee243547dee91fbd053c1c4a845aa-Paper.pdf) of course, they use a more sophisticated function, but it's still deterministic.

It can seem strange to add both embeddings together, but the Transformer isn't confused since the variability it sees in embedded inputs isn't caused by a blend of word and positional embeddings, it's only caused by the word embedding. Positional encoding changes every input in the same way.

Comment: I disagree with what you say. Although the positional encoding is deterministic, it still varies. Hence, the variability is caused by both the embedding and the positional encoding.

Comment: Are you referring to a specific positional embedding method? It might help to know what you have in mind :)

Comment: No, the specific positional encoding is unrelated to my question. My point is that the resulting word embedding (`word1`), has two degrees of freedom. Hence, it is unknown how the positional encoding and original embedding influence this.

Comment: Well, it's not unrelated. Try to compute it by hand and you'll see it doesn't vary.